# If every ideal is a direct summand, then every module is injective

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, injective-module

I am trying to prove the following result:

> Let $R$ be an algebra. Show that every $R$-module is injective if, and only if, every ideal is a direct summand of $R$.

The $(\Rightarrow)$ implication is very easy, but the other way around is giving me trouble for quite some time now. For this problem, I would rather have a hint other than a full answer, but either is fine.

Comment: *Hint*: use Baer's criterion.

Comment: Thank you, @Bernard.  It worked out.